# How do I pass a custom argument to myself through Facebook's graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to pass a custom argument/identifier to myself through a call to Facebook's graph API (to help me identify where I sent the original graph api call from, and for other useful information).

What's the best method for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible by appending a parameter to a Graph Call as the API only returns a response based on the specifications the API was built under.